# can we do scaling by throwing ruby stone

Tags: ruby, mobile, scalability, language-discussion, desktop-development

1. I heard developers at my office discussing Ruby language can be used for following purposes: Desktop apps,Web Apps,and may be handheld devices.
   Actually,we are in phase of selecting technology to have scalability of  the following:
2. I have - Ruby made Desktop apps on each inventory unit of the big firm.
   And wish to synchronize all relevant data from those desktop apps to a web app DWarehouse like Dropbox for some ontology and mining work.
   And wish to have some wireless chat app also on handsets like whatsapp to assist in faster communication between inventory unit managers.
3. So,can we get a faster good build of Desktop apps,web apps and handset chat apps using ruby technology.
4. And I know ruby can't be scaled up for large workload,then what we can do later,should we get some java or php support to scale the application base or there is some cloud option present for ruby.

Answer (score 1):

Your architecture scales, not your language.

Ruby has many frameworks and tools that help with building an scalable architecture. But it's on you how you will use them.

Rails seems to easily scale for web apps and have a bunch of web servers. But abuse of session  data (like adding 1MB things into the session), or machine specific information and your app won't be able to scale so easily.

Comment: I'm convinced,what you are saying is perfectly valid,then why twitter used scala for its backend expandibility,if ruby has so much to support scalable architecture. tha's the thing which creates dilemma.

Comment: Are you going to build twitter II? http://www.unlimitednovelty.com/2009/04/twitter-blaming-ruby-for-their-mistakes.html

There are opinions for everything. And the idea of "choosing the right tool for the right job" applies everywhere. But if ruby in your architecture does the job for you, continue with it till you find something specific that it cannot do "for you".